# Sending a message from Chrome extension side panel to content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension that needs to manipulate the DOM according to checkboxes ticked in the side panel.

I am trying to do that by storing which checkboxes are ticked in the chrome local storage, then sending a message from the side panel script to the content script to run the DOM script that retreives the params stored in local storage then manipulates the DOM accordingly.
My extension does not register a background script.

I have tried multiple methods revolving around **chrome.tabs.sendMessage** but I keep running into the same error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.
```

Here is my code :

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Name",
    "description": "Description",
    "version": "1.0",
    "side_panel": {
        "default_path": "./sidepanel/sidepanel.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "sidePanel",
        "storage",
        "tabs",
        "activeTab"
    ],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["www.pageurl.com/*"],
            "js": ["./utilities/background.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

sidepanel.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    [...]
    <body>
        [...]
        <input id="triggerBtn" type="checkbox" name="" class="switch is-rounded is-outlined is-info" />
        [...]
    </body>
    <script src="./sidepanel.js"></script>
</html>
```

sidepanel.js :

```
document.getElementById("triggerBtn").addEventListener("click", () => {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        var tab = tabs[0];
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "TEST");
    });
});
```

utilities/background.js :

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    console.log(message);
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: When you install, update, or reload the extension its content scripts won't run in open tabs in Chrome, so you need to use executeScript explicitly in sendMessage's `catch`, then call sendMessage again.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error when there's cases where there's not necessarily a receiving end to your message. This makes it quite complicated to implement.

However, in your case there's never a receiving end; you need to put a service worker between you content script and popup/sidepanel script to pass on messages.

Also; pretty sure "tabs" permission eliminates the need for "activeTab".